# Gmail API .NET GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync Leaves Browser Waiting

Tags: c#, gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-oauth

I'm using the .NET library to access the Gmail API.  I'm basically just doing the [quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet) and it does work, but after giving authorization in the web browser, the browser stays spinning/waiting.  I would expect the browser window to close, or give a message that the access token has been provided, but it just stays blank with the cursor spinning.  Here is my code:

```
private async Task Authorize()
{
    string[] Scopes = { GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom };
    credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        new ClientSecrets
        {
            ClientId = "<myclientid>.apps.googleusercontent.com",
            ClientSecret = "<myclientsecret>"
        },
        Scopes,
        UserEmail,
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore("Somepath"));

    // Create Gmail API service.
    var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = String.Format("MyCompany-{0}-v{1}", Constants.szAppName, Constants.VERSION),
    });

    // Define parameters of request.
    UsersResource.LabelsResource.ListRequest request = service.Users.Labels.List("me");

    // List labels.
    IList<Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Label> labels = request.Execute().Labels;
    Console.WriteLine("Labels:");
    if (labels != null && labels.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var labelItem in labels)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", labelItem.Name);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No labels found.");
    }
}
```

Even though it provides the access token and functions, I'd like to clean it up by having the browser finish/stop.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like it might be https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/540 - what version of Google.Apis.Gmail.v1 are you using? Which VS version? What browser are you using? And exactly what state is the browser left in? Thanks.

Comment: Google.Apis.Gmail.v1: 1.25.0.783.  VS2015.  Chrome (Also tested on IE with same result).  The browser displays the URL: http://localhost:51336/authorize/?code=<access_code> but the page is completely blank.  The status bar says "Waiting for play.google.com...".  The tab shows a spinning circle cursor, like it is waiting.

Comment: OK, that's the latest library version. If you leave the browser does it eventually timeout with some sort of network error message? And do you have any idea why the status bar mentions "play.google.com"? The auth process itself shouldn't have anything to do it! I suspect this bug is that in some circumstances the localhost server socket is being shutdown too soon. Unfortunately I haven't been able to reproduce the error yet.

Comment: It never times out.  I've left it for a couple hours, and it stays in that same state.  No, I don't have any idea why it mentions play.google.com.  If you'd like to test with the program you can download [Remind-Me](https://www.beiley.com/remind-me/download.html).  Create a new event, go to the "Email" tab, enable email, press "Configure..." and set up the mail server as smtp.gmail.com and then press "Get Authorization".

Comment: Thanks for the info. I hope to work on reproducing/fixing this problem fairly soon, and it'll be tracked under https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/540

Comment: Thanks @Chris.  I've subscribed to that thread.

Comment: Hi @Chris, I saw you closed the issue on GitHub.  You're not able to reproduce this?  I can still reproduce it...

Comment: Hi Mark, we'll continue following this up on the github issue: https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/540